# How to persist SignalR connection ID

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I’m trying to build a chat apps whereby users id are represented by their auto generated signalR connection id. On page refresh, the connection id changes when a new connection is instantiated. Is there a way to persist the state of the connection id of a user until the browser session is ended (i.e until he ends his session on client).

Any guide or documentation? It really would help.

i am new in signalr. so trying to know many things searching Google. from this url i got a similar snippet http://kevgriffin.com/maintaining-signalr-connectionids-across-page-instances/

they are saying it is possible. the problem is signalr often create a new connection id if we referesh the page. i want to prevent this but how.......

this code snippet.

```
public class MyConnectionFactory : IConnectionIdFactory
    {
        public string CreateConnectionId(IRequest request)
        {
            if (request.Cookies["srconnectionid"] != null)
            {
                return request.Cookies["srconnectionid"];
            }

            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        alert("Connected!");
        var myClientId = $.connection.hub.id;
        setCookie("srconnectionid", myClientId);
    });

    function setCookie(cName, value, exdays) {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie = cName + "=" + c_value;
    }
```

my doubt is does it work in all signalr version? if not then how to handle it in new version specially for not generate a new connection id if page gets refreshed. looking for suggestion.

if we work with Persistent connection class instead of hub then what happen.....in this case connection id will persist if we refresh the page at client side? please guide.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignalR allows you to send messages to a user via their `IPrincipal.Identity.Name`. Just use `Clients.User(userName)` instead of `Clients.Client(connectionId)`.

If you for some reason cannot address a user using their `IPrincipal.Identity.Name` you could create your own [IUserIdProvider](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider). This is the replacement for `IConnectionIdFactory` which no longer exists in SignalR >= 1.0.0.

The equivalent `IUserIdProvider` would look like this:

```
public class MyConnectionFactory : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request.Cookies["srconnectionid"] != null)
        {
            return request.Cookies["srconnectionid"];
        }

        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var idProvider = new MyConnectionFactory();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string userName, string message)
    {
        return Clients.User(userName).receive(message);
    }
}
```

It would be really trivial to spoof a user given this `MyConnectionFactory`. You could make it more secure by using an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

Ideally you would just use the [default IUserIdProvider](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Infrastructure/PrincipalUserIdProvider.cs) which retrieves the user ID from `IRequest.User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: thanks for answer. what signalr version i need to use to run your code. i was working with signalr and VS2010 IDE. so tell me does your code works for VS2010 version?

Comment: what is the difference between Clients.User(userName) and 
Clients.Client(connectionId) approach. user name may not be unique but connectionId is always unique. so what will happen if userName is not unique? please guide. thanks

Comment: IConnectionIdFactory was removed in SignalR 1.0.0. IUserIdProvider was introduced in SignalR 2.0.0. Your VS version shouldn't matter. You are correct that can be multiple SignalR connections with the same userName. For example, the same user might have a SignalR app open in multiple browser tabs. In that situation, every connection belonging to the user with userName will receive the messages sent to that user using Clients.User(userName).

Comment: what is the difference between Clients.User(userName) and Clients.Client(connectionId) approach ? hub and client is mapped by connection id so one thing is not clear that how this line could work Clients.User(userName) ? how Clients.User(userName).ClientFunctionName() could fire at right client side? can u plzz elaborate this things. thanks

Comment: Sorry....i need one small help that if i use IUserIdProvider then connection id will persist even i refresh the page? you do not provide signalr client side js code. if possible add it here so i can see how you store the connetion id in cookie and also make the provision as a result connection id will persist even page referesh.

Comment: which signalr version is required for IUserIdProvider interface ? how to register the dependency called IUserIdProvider from global.asax instead of start up file. if possible show me with code

Comment: @halter73 Does this approach ( userId) saves me from dealing with dictionary who maps users<-->ConnectionID ? I mean  , a client can connects/reconnects 100 times ( and get different guids)  and I don't care about this , I  will just have to send to  Clients.User.... right?

Comment: @halter73 Asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277492/signalrs-iuseridprovider-clarification)

Answer (score 0):

The user id provider doesn't work, because the connection id doesn't come from it. I implemented a solution (https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/persisting-signalr-connections-across-page-reloads) that uses a pseudo-session id stored in session storage. Every SignalR connection id is then mapped to this pseudo-session id.

Comment: Please don't post the (almost) the same answer to multiple questions. If they are duplicates, then use your close votes. If they are not, then try to tailor your answers to those specific questions. Additionally, please don't post link-only answers. You can provide (a part of) the code here and use the link for reference.